# GNUPlot Draw label on x2y2 axes

Tags: position, label, gnuplot, axis

I want to place a label on a plot which uses autoscale.

To keep the label at the same position i want to use alternative axis which don't use autoscale to get an absolute location.

How can I choose the uses axis of a "set label" statement?

```
set y2range [0:10]
set x2range [0:100]
set label "FooBar" at 10, 5
```

Line 3: something is missing here. "axes x2y2" wont work (used in plot label functions)

Thanks for helping me out here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different coordinate systems which you can use to place labels (see `help coordinates` in the interactive terminal):

- `first`, uses the first axis (x, y) as reference
- `second`, uses the second axis (x2, y2) as reference
- `screen`, relative to the canvas size
- `graph`, relative to the plot size
- `character`, in character units.

So the best way to get an absolute location inside the plot is with `graph`:

```
set label "FooBar" at graph 0.2, 0.2
```

You can also mix the coordinate systems:

```
set label "FooBar" at graph 0.2, screen 0.5
```