# gnuplot: position min / max value using y2-axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have a further question to this one: [find and position min / max values in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130639/gnuplot-how-to-plot-max-and-or-min-value).
Now i have two graphs in one plot with different y-axis ranges (xy- and x2y2-axis). The graph which i want to label with min/max values is defined by x2y2 range. The problem is, that the coordinates for the min/max values are used from xy range and not from x2y2 range. Therefore the labels are not at their correct position.

Comment: With `set label at second...` you use the secondary axes as coordinate system for the position.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/22227638/2604213